# DataReader does not return data but the number of rows

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have this code

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM table;"

try
{
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
   {
      connection.Open();

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
      {
         SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      }

      connection.Close();
   }
}
```

In reader I receive the number of rows in the table, but no data. Where am I getting lost?

Comment: You need to loop through the reader (`while (reader.Read())`...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the reader

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader#:~:text=To%20retrieve%20data%20using%20a,rows%20from%20a%20data%20source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader#:%7E:text=To%20retrieve%20data%20using%20a,rows%20from%20a%20data%20source).

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
           // 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you've called `ExecuteReader` you need to loop through it, reading each row:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
  // Process the row...
}
```

Also, it's good practice to put the reader into a `using` block:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  while(reader.Read())
  {
    // Process the row
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, it would be even more helpful when you add some example code how to access a single row and its data.